# Manage ng-if from another controller

Tags: angularjs

I have prepared a Plunkr that provides the code:

https://plnkr.co/edit/WXtQxVcdgyvnaajbs4eJ?p=preview

I have assigned the object **$scope.menu.show** in controller **toolbarCtrl** that controls whether the menu is created or not.

```
<md-menu id="menu" ng-controller="toolbarCtrl" ng-if="true"> ...
```

When **toolbarCtrl** gets initialized I can control whether the menu is shown but I would like to control it from another controller. In this case I created two buttons in **mainCtrl** that produce **true** or **false** and I'm trying to assign the value to the **$rootScope** but that doesn't work.

How can I do that?

**UPDATE:** 
Although  jtmingus solution works perfectly I came up with another solution that doesn't need events.

I created this factory service:

```
app.factory('menuState', function () {
  var state = {val: false};
  function getState() {
    return state;
  }
  function setState(newState) {
    state.val = newState;
  }
  return {
    getState: getState,
    setState: setState
  }
});
```

Then at the toolbarCtrl controller I initially hide the menu

```
app.controller('toolbarCtrl', function($scope, menuState) {
  // hide the menu
  menuState.setState(false);

  // pass the value to the menu
  $scope.state = menuState.getState();
});
```

on the mainCtrl I define the button clicks like that:

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, menuState) {
   $scope.state = menuState.setState;
});
```

and 2 buttons on the the main.html

```
<md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="setState(true)">Show</md-button>
<md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="setState(false)">Hide</md-button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that data generally should be shared through controllers is by using a service.  Because you need both controllers to watch the same state, you can use Angular's events, specifically the `$on` event.

Here is an article that will walk you through having multiple controllers watch the same state:

https://variadic.me/posts/2013-10-15-share-state-between-controllers-in-angularjs.html

**Edit:** After looking through this article some more, I realized it's not the best explanation, and there are some things in the code that don't work.  For example, if you try to pass arguments in with a `$broadcast` call, the `$on` function needs two paramaters–event and args.

Comment: I have added the Plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/WXtQxVcdgyvnaajbs4eJ?p=preview with a service but it seems the service variable doesn't update the controller scope. Can you have a look?

Comment: @DittmarConsulting You need to add Angular events.  One controller can't know that the service's variable is updated without them..  If you read the article I shared, you will understand how to do it. It's super clear and easy to follow

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/EOcW0009qAZSu0PslCSR?p=preview Here's a working Plunker.  I used ```$broadcast``` in the service and ```$on``` in the controller

Comment: Nice work. Thanks for that. In the meantime I got it working without events. Nevertheless it's better to have 2 solutions than non.

Comment: Just because I'm curious, what did you do to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

On the controller from which you want to initiate showing the menu,

```
app
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.$broadcast('menu:show');
}])
.controller('ToolbarCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     var ToolbarCtrl = this;
     $scope.$on('menu:show', function() {
        ToolbarCtrl.showMenu = true;
     });
}])
```

In the markup switch using this value

```
<md-menu id="menu" ng-controller="ToolbarCtrl" ng-if="ToolbarCtrl.showMenu"> ...
```

Comment: I updated my Plunkr with the suggestion you have provided but it didn't work. Have a look here https://plnkr.co/edit/WXtQxVcdgyvnaajbs4eJ?p=preview